# Link custom Docker container to MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, apache, docker, yii

I have a customized Apache2/PHP container that I want to link to my MySQL one.

Both containers are running **via Rancher**.

The Dockerfile that created the image fro the Apache2 container looks like this:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y upgrade && DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive apt-get -y install \
    apache2 php7.0 php7.0-mysql libapache2-mod-php7.0 curl lynx-cur libpng-dev curl libcurl4-openssl-dev

RUN docker-php-ext-install mysql mysqli pdo pdo_mysql gd curl

RUN a2enmod php7.0
RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN service apache2 restart
```

This container runs a Yii 1 application, which runs just fine on a regular undockerized LAMP stack. This container is simply liked via Rancher to a regular mysql:latest container. I also have an phpmyadmin container that just connects fine to that. I checked the permissions and passwords of the user that is supposed to connect to the mysql container like a 1000 times and they seem to be fine.

Nevertheless, I always get an Yii *CDbConnection failed to open the DB connection.*

The error I get (looking at the log files) is the following:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue (combination of different things):

- www-data had not read/write access
- The image was changed to php:7.0-apache
- Removed mysql from the docker-php-ext-install
- I found out that my config file was not correct (it referenced db-address localhost, it was set to the link name)